# MVC3 Data Annotations Regular Expression validator Attribute failing

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

One of my view models has a property, GramWeight, defined as

```
    [Display(Name="Gram Weight")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Gram Weight must be a Number.")]
    [Range(0, 9999.99, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between 0 - 9,999.99")]
    public decimal? GramWeight { get; set; }
```

The validation on this field fails when the user enters a value with a leading decimal point, such as .23 as opposed to 0.23.  If the user adds the 0 to the front, the validation passes.  I had assumed this was a problem with my regular expression, but I ran some tests at this http://regexhero.net/tester/ and it seems to work just fine.

So, if it's not the regular expression, is it something else?  I'm about ready to use javascript to append a 0 for the user if they fail to do so.  That's kind of my last resort option, but I'm considering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because it's a decimal type, have you tried changing `GramWeight` to a string just to see what the validator does in that case?

Comment: OK, it seems when I change the property type to string then it works.  While that explains the problem, I'm not sure I like the idea of my model representing all my decimal fields as strings. Great for the view, I suppose, but nowhere else. Since my Models often serve as Domain objects, this really blows.  Thanks for the solution though.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of javascript might be called for to prefix with a zero if it starts with a decimal point. Are you also using client side validation/input filtering?

Comment: Yes I am.  I'm new to a lot of this stuff. What would be the best way to catch the leading decimal and append a zero? I was thinking on the blur. And if I do this, will it fire before the client side validation fires.

Comment: you could just prefix the zero at the point you call the server-side code. But changing the input to have a zero as the user leaves it could be confusing for the user. If possible, and if you're writing this for a client of some kind you could try asking them if they have a preference or even prototyping in for them. I'd recommend using Jing if you can't get something in front o them, then you can talk them through the issue.

Comment: I recommend not using View Models as domain objects.  Also Everything inputted by the users are really just strings. The auto binding to the View Models can convert a proper string to a int etc.  However, some users might do stuff like 1,000 and that would fail to bind.  I suggest taking in all as strings and running a regexpr to validate.  Once in the controller validate and then have the controller simply be in charge of converting the View Models into a domain object then calling out to whatever business logic or crud you need to execute.

Comment: BTW I have just switched over to MVC3 from MVC2 so unless the auto binding got more advanced then I'd stick to strings for user inputted data.  For user selected data like a select box you can use properly typed data.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need a better solution here is a proper regular expression to validate decimal numbers:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]?[0-9]")]
```

This regex requires a number (zero in your case) before the dot sign and allows maximum 2 decimals.

Comment: I wanted to allow a leading decimal, without 0.  And I need more than one decimal place in many cases. .00125 is a common value.